# Kafka service broken after applying ACL

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

I'm configuring a kafka 3-node cluster (version 3.2.0) on which I plan to use ACL for authorization. For the moment I am using SASL for authentication and  StandardAuthorizer for authorization (I am using kraft).
I set the ACL successfully with this command :

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh --command-config /usr/local/kafka/config/kraft/adminclient-config.conf --bootstrap-server <broker hostname>:9092 --add --allow-principal User:* --allow-host <ip> --operation Read --operation Write --topic <topic name>
```

But then whenever I restart a broker it fails with a similar error:

```
 ERROR [StandardAuthorizer 1] addAcl error (org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizerData)
java.lang.RuntimeException: An ACL with ID JjIHfwV4TMi5yo9oPXMxWw already exists.
```

It seems like it always tries to reapply the ACL, is this normal?
How can I fix this?

Thanks

I tried to exclude authentication issues removing the SSL settings and keeping just the SASL settings.
I would expect that on a cluster setup the addition or removal of an ACL is propagated to all the brokers, and if not at least that the broker state were not broken.

Answer (score 1):

we have a cluster with the same configuration. We are facing problems configuring ACLs too. But in our case we are not able to make work the StandardAuthorizer. When starting the server, it raises a AuthorizerNotReadyException.

This is our configuration to enable the ACL authorizer in server.properties:

```
authorizer.class.name=org.apache.kafka.metadata.authorizer.StandardAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
super.users=User:admin
```

Respect to your server.properties configuration file, do you find any difference?

Maybe if we succeed to run the same configuration, we can see if we incur in the same problem your are experiencing and look for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is broken in 3.2.3. If you check the server logs when adding the ACL, you will see that the duplicate error shows up already at that point. Then indeed the broker won't come up if you restart it.

That specific issue seems fixed in 3.4.0. Unfortunately there is a different issue when using ACLs on this version. See https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/23237

So as far as I know, it's not currently possible to use ACLs when running in KRaft mode with multiple brokers.